# CSS file not loading in Freemarker Dropwizard

Tags: html, css, freemarker, dropwizard

I know this is a dumb question, but my Freemarker view isn't loading the css file, despite the fact that they in in the same package, in the resource.  I've used the following links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="absolute path here">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resource/views/styles.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Is there a proper way to do this in an ftl file?  I'd rather not have to code in the style on each page.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS (and JavaScript) files are loaded by the browser. FreeMarker has nothing to do with it. The path you have in the `href` is resolved by the browser based on the URL you see in the address bar of the browser (unless you have a `base` element in the HTML `head`).

Last time I have worked with some Dropwizard project it used `bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle());` in the `Application.initialize` method, and then there were `src/main/resources/assets/whatever.css`, and then in the template `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/whatever.css">` or `href="/assets/whatever.css">`, depending on how the URL-s of you pages will look for the user.